# Ignore empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have some dummy data and I want to get just data that are not empty.

https://codesandbox.io/s/broken-firefly-8tb82?file=/src/App.js

I don't want to include the object that has empty data. And also I don't want to get the object that has id similar to another.

```
const dummyData = [
  {
  id: 'GA2',
  name: 'First',
  },
  {
  id: 'GA2',
  name: 'Second',
  },
  {
  id: '',
  name: '',
  },
  {
  id: 'GA3',
  name: 'Third',
  },
  ];
```

`console.log('dummy data', dummyData.map(({ name, id }) => ( { name, id: id.length !== 0 } )));`

`id.length !== 0` seems isn't good way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one approach that remove objects with duplicate IDs as well as with empty id:

```js
const dummyData = [{
    id: 'GA1',
    name: 'First',
  },
  {
    id: 'GA3',
    name: 'Third',
  },
  {
    id: 'GA2',
    name: 'Second',
  },
  {
    id: '',
    name: '',
  },
  {
    id: 'GA3',
    name: 'Third',
  },
];

const output = dummyData.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  return curr.id && !acc.filter(({
    id
  }) => id === curr.id).length ? [...acc, curr] : acc
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're returning object's that look like the following from your map.

```
{
  id: true,
  name: "First"
}
```

You'd ideally wanna just filter the array by it's contents.

```
dummyData.filter(o => o.id && o.name);
```

Filter takes true or false, and if false, does not return the item. Map will always return an item, even if you don't - it will fill that index of the array with undefined.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `filter`, below will discard the duplicate `ids` as well as empty objects

```js
var dummyData = [ { id: 'GA2', name: 'First', }, { id: 'GA2', name: 'Second', }, { id: '', name: '', }, { id: 'GA3', name: 'Third', } ];

var result = dummyData.filter((val,i,self)=>val.id && val.name && self.findIndex(k=>k.id==val.id)==i);

console.log(result);
```